# Can I integrate Facebook events into a ionic app?

Tags: facebook, cordova, ionic-framework

I am doing an ionic app and I need that when I click a button inside my app, the user logged in, set on a facebook event "I'm going".
Is it possible with a plugin or something?

I am going to show you and example. 
I have events created on facebook (public all), and in my app, I have a button that tells, YES I'M GOING. (The user is logged in by his facebook account). I need that in the facebook event appears that user like a new user that goes to the event.

I need a solution as soon as possible.

Thanks a million!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try doing a POST request to the `attending` endpoint of an event:

```
/xxx/attending
```

Replace "xxx" with your event ID.

API Explorer example: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=POST&path=[event-id]%2Fattending

Also, you need to authorize the user with the `rsvp_event` permission for that. So you have to implement user authorization, there is no plugin or easier way for a "one click solution".